# How to convert png base 64 to pixel array with out using image.src or image.onload?

Tags: javascript, image, png, pixel

I was wondering how to load base64 on sites that have CSPs that don't allow it. Meaning we can't do stuff like:

```
image.src = "data:image/png;base64..."
```

So I figured I needed to find a different approach. I tried converting the base64 into a binary string then working from that to get a UintArray containing the pixel image data.

I don't know how to get and image out of the *loadImage* function, nor do I know what I'm doing wrong when getting the pixel(s).

I know that the conversion from the binary string to the pixel array is wrong, base64 must have some type of way of converting it, that is unknown to most of us.

Here is my code that tries to solve this:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        var imageBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,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";

        canvas.width = 540;
        canvas.height = 360;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function loadImage(base64)
        {
            var binary_string = window.atob(base64.split(",")[1]);
            var len = binary_string.length;
            var pixels = new Uint8Array(len);

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        
            {
                pixels[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            putImageData(ctx, {
                data: pixels,
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            }, 0, 0);



            var img = new Image();
            img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; 

            console.log(pixels);

            return img;
        }

        loadImage(imageBase64);

        //ctx.drawImage(loadImage(imageBase64), 0, 0);



        function putImageData(ctx, imageData, dx, dy, dirtyX, dirtyY, dirtyWidth, dirtyHeight) 
        {
            var data = imageData.data;
            var height = imageData.height;
            var width = imageData.width;

            dirtyX = dirtyX || 0;
            dirtyY = dirtyY || 0;
            dirtyWidth = dirtyWidth !== undefined ? dirtyWidth : width;
            dirtyHeight = dirtyHeight !== undefined ? dirtyHeight : height;

            var limitBottom = dirtyY + dirtyHeight;
            var limitRight = dirtyX + dirtyWidth;

            for (var y = dirtyY; y < limitBottom; y++) 
            {
                for (var x = dirtyX; x < limitRight; x++) 
                {
                    var pos = y * width + x;
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + data[pos * 4 + 0]
                                    + ',' + data[pos * 4 + 1]
                                    + ',' + data[pos * 4 + 2]
                                    + ',' + (data[pos * 4 + 3] / 255) + ')';
                    ctx.fillRect(x + dx, y + dy, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Maybe if we can find out how the base64 works then we can do it.
And with that:
Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: The base64 part of the data url is the base64 encoded file content. This file content, of course, isn't raw pixel data, instead it's the pixel data rearranged and compressed to be more convenient for reading, writing, storage, and transfer. The reason you see `Image.src` used is because it's the only way to get the browser to natively decode the file data and turn it into raw pixel data. If you want to do without `Image.src`, you're going to have to figure out how to decode images yourself. There's a [PNG file format specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) over on W3C. Good luck!

Comment: Also, one of the base64 specifications is [over here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for browserify [here generated file (480kB)](https://pastebin.com/SN2vwZeg):

```
var PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

function getPNG(bin) {
    return PNG.sync.read(bin);
}

function loadImage(base64)
{
    var binary_string = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');

    var png = getPNG(binary_string);

    return png;
}

window.getPNG = getPNG;
window.loadImage = loadImage;
```

And snippet demo:

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw/SN2vwZeg"></script>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var imageBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAB4CAYAAAC0CXGGAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAMxSURBVHhe7doxaFNRGAXg6KRxlyRD4hpqqUEoTqJTaZcWTBeXoIPgEHcNCArR3TcIDpUsLq3QLi1Z1FECEitiVtshDe52jDbeM/Sd3ub3NtH7cvt/i6cgD6/5T9+9L+9MytHa2tovxD/K5bLzNQ4b9Xpn8efE0gX4Js4bz+ib+jaScbs2g2RIMzzu6+kI+RZeB6QZZePuAJOuryPkW/gdaLfbSHalUgnpZFyvrx1ImvA6wGq1WqwTmUwGyWi1WkhGPp9Hstvd3UUyZmdnkYxer4dk1Ov1of9GHSHfwuuANPPV9ddIdrVr80h29Y9bSHbR0h0kQ+qEjpBv4XWA90Jsb28PyY5nlnGnWDabRbLTvVDShNcBJp0PpL0Rk/Y+0v6f6Qj5Fn4HoiiKdeD9yg8k48Ll70jGz6+XkOykv3/z7kUko1qtagcS7fR1gHEnigt9JLvOZvz/jGeeaQeSLvwO8F5oY2MDya7T6SDZFYtFJLvFxUUkQ/dCSRdeB6QzsfQ8v9lsItnNzc0h2UnfN+iZOGnC78D9rWUk417mEZLBMy/9nuf7BHfiVe8ZkvFyfhXJ0A4kzenrACtsX0UyXDuwM/MJyU47kHThdUA6Az/9/ADJ4A6kHxaQ7Paf7yAZ3IHHV14g2fEZWUfIt/A6wPcB6TuxRqOBZLjeByqVCpIdf2em94GkCb8Drs+BXDsw6nMiHSHfJr8D0nMg7gC/E8dnYte9EJ+J+Z067gDTEfItvA7w3kd6/2fcz4UYv4vBeyMdId8mvwPX396KdWC5ewPJkN7/+dd7IX6/aDX3AcnQEfItvA6wwnoayeCZ5DOx616Iz8TcuZ2lfSQ7HSHfJr8D0nkgac+FmH4Crp/AqNfr9/vF6Wn8MJDuDF9AAsVWpL+FfPvvC+h2u8NL4Eg/Ad90Ab6JCxh36cZt5E+g0XBbYC6XO9jc0O2Wbk6DN6oRoFpFGIhvpv5OFCEc490KAhQXEI7xbRMB+B/MYgsYonH+JKs74LqAw6aGb55SRz5h+pl3T1PCBcVFSiPF4zPqAsbnyPdtMZEwhk/oJYz8l/hLGOdqww/bSimllFJKKaWUi1TqN5LWUoxlg3+MAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var png = loadImage(imageBase64.split(",")[1]);

putImageData(ctx, {
        data: png.data,
        width: png.width,
        height: png.height
    }, 0, 0);


function putImageData(ctx, imageData, dx, dy, dirtyX, dirtyY, dirtyWidth, dirtyHeight) 
{
    var data = imageData.data;
    var height = imageData.height;
    var width = imageData.width;

    dirtyX = dirtyX || 0;
    dirtyY = dirtyY || 0;
    dirtyWidth = dirtyWidth !== undefined ? dirtyWidth : width;
    dirtyHeight = dirtyHeight !== undefined ? dirtyHeight : height;

    var limitBottom = dirtyY + dirtyHeight;
    var limitRight = dirtyX + dirtyWidth;

    for (var y = dirtyY; y < limitBottom; y++) 
    {
        for (var x = dirtyX; x < limitRight; x++) 
        {
            var pos = y * width + x;
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + data[pos * 4 + 0]
                            + ',' + data[pos * 4 + 1]
                            + ',' + data[pos * 4 + 2]
                            + ',' + (data[pos * 4 + 3] / 255) + ')';
            ctx.fillRect(x + dx, y + dy, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, I know how to do that. But in this case I can't use image.src. Maybe reread my question and try again. Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: No wait it just gives me the same thing as it's browser.js file. So it is fine. I just don't know how to get fs to work.

Comment: Yeah I know about CORS, and no I want to keep it as base64 in one file. That is loaded in a web site. CORS won't let me load the file as a image.src.

Comment: Browserified script is on lines 13859 - 13875 in the generated file. Btw your picture data are incomplete - should have around 903 bytes, but have only 800, so lib reported an error with original. There is strange difference between Buffer in node.js and browser - did not worked with browser's and Buffer of node.js is unknown outside Browserify IIFE.

Comment: I think it is just this image, I may have not copied the whole string or something. It works for other images, though. I could've never figured out how to use it on my own.

Comment: Also spent some time playing with, but as I worked in and love R&D, it was pleasure to find how easily you can connect node.js and browser "worlds" thanx 2 browserify ;-) And Charlie's hint...

Answer (score 2):

Unlike how you maybe expecting, the binary data representing a PNG image are not an array of pixels. The binary data has headers and various meta data describing the file, then a compressed image.

If you need to get pixels out of a png binary without using the native browser decoding functionality, you either have to study the PNG format yourself or use a specialized library which will give you access to the pixels of the image.

Thee are many image libraries which support the PNG format. Following is a specialized library which can do the trick for you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs

You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to use this library in the front end.

Comment: How am I supposed to decode it using pngjs exactly? What is the method?

Comment: Well, you will have to refer the documentation, experiment and post more questions when they arise along your way. Good luck.

Comment: I think I'll come back to this!